# How to access a JS model from a JS script in the public folder using Sequelize and Phaser

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, sequelize.js, phaser-framework

I'm working on an in-browser boardgame using Phaser where the boardgame tiles are generated based on data pulled from mysql DB.  I want the player to be able to select a game tile via click and then click a button to take ownership of that same tile.  Currently, the tiles are successfully generated and clicking on a game tile adds that tile's information to an array named "activeTile".

Clicking the "CLAIM" button should update the Mapset model to change ownership of the tile with id (activeTile[0]) to the string stored in the playerName variable.  The issue is that I am unable to touch the Mapset model.  I've tried both "require" and "import" but both throw errors.

I first tried adding

```
const Mapset = require("../../Models/Mapset");
```

to the first line of game.js and that returned the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

then I replaced that with

```
import Mapset from "../../Models/Mapset";
```

but that threw an error as well

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Phaser CLAIM button code in game.js

```
    //onclick should update DB via model
    button.on('pointerdown', function () {
        console.log('Button clicked!');
         Mapset.update({
            own: playerName
                }, {
                where: {
                   id: activeTile[0]
                   }
            }).then(function (result) {
              console.log("Data updated successfully!");
            });
    });
```

Mapset model in Mapset.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../config/connection");

class Mapset extends Model { }

Mapset.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        x: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        y: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        spr: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        def: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        res: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        own: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true,
        modelName: "Mapset",
        timestamps: false
    },
);

module.exports = Mapset;
```

[image: File Structure]

Comment: You have to differenciate your nodejs server side code and the javascript code you execute in the browser. What's running in the browser can't have any knowledge of your files on your server, your model etc. If you want the two being able to communicate you'll have to create REST entrypoints with express for example and trigger the server operations through http requests.

Comment: @Peterrabbit  That was the issue.  Thank you.  Do you want to set your comment as the answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to differenciate your nodejs server side code and the javascript code you execute in the browser. What's running in the browser can't have any knowledge of your files on your server, your model etc. If you want the two being able to communicate you'll have to create REST entrypoints with express for example and trigger the server operations through http requests.